# How can I fix my VS code C++ setup so that I can initialize my vector as I would normally in Xcode or any other IDE?

Tags: string, visual-studio-code, vector

I am trying to initialize a vector in my main.cpp like so:
`vector <string> options = {"add", "remove", "print", "printList"};`

but I get an error that says cannot be initialized using {}

I am using VS code and have tried changing a lot of settings to get it to work but I don't know where I am falling short. I think it might have something to do with my compiler, but when I try the same thing in Xcode it works perfectly fine. I have vector and string included. Anything helps because I have spent way too long trying to figure this out on my own.

Comment: Where do you get this error?  In VS Code "Problems" as an intellisense error? Or somewhere else.  Look at your .vscode\c_cpp_properties.json if your compiler and standards are correct.

Comment: ad the c++ version you want to use in the compiler options or intellisense json file:  any of c++11, c++14, c++17, c++20

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you! Everything is rolling smoothly now!